# OnDrop: how to determine which mouse button is being used?

Tags: c++, mfc, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a "drag and drop" functionality into a program (for Windows, written in C++, with MFC).

A class is derived from `COleDropTarget`, it has the `OnDragOver` and `OnDrop` functions overridden.
In `OnDragOver`, a parameter `dwKeyState` tells me which mouse button is being used to "drag", and what "interesting" keys are pressed on the keyboard.

In `OnDrop`, this parameter is not passed (neither is it in `OnDropEx`).

Now, the question is: if I need to know this information "at droptime", how do I determine it?

The only way I found out is to store it in a static variable in `OnDragOver` and then retrieve it in `OnDrop`.
But I'm not satisfied (i.e. I can't believe I'm doing it the right way) because:

1. Is it guaranteed that the last `OnDragOver` reflects the final
   situation at the "drop" time? (for the mouse button: **if** it's
   possible that it may change, like if the user presses a button,
   starts dragging, then presses the other button, releases the first
   one, and then "drops"... don't know. But for the keys, the situation
   is surely able to change when the user presses or releases <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>
   and <kbd>Shift</kbd> while dragging)
2. If the answer is "yes":

   - If I have to remember information from `OnDragOver` anyway, why does
     the system pass all the other data (`pWnd`, `pDataObject`, `dropEffect`,
     `point`) again to `OnDrop`? What's the point?
   - Why does the documentation say that "*typically, the application
     overrides `OnDropEx` in the view class to handle right mouse-button
     drag and drop*"? If `OnDropEx` can't even tell which mouse button has
     just been used?!?
3. If the answer to 1. is "no": so, what's the correct way to
   determine the mouse button just used and the pressed keys?

Thanks for any help...

Functions prototypes:

```
    virtual DROPEFFECT OnDragOver(CWnd* pWnd, COleDataObject* pDataObject, DWORD dwKeyState, CPoint point);
    virtual BOOL OnDrop(CWnd* pWnd, COleDataObject* pDataObject, DROPEFFECT dropEffect, CPoint point);
    virtual DROPEFFECT OnDropEx(CWnd* pWnd, COleDataObject* pDataObject, DROPEFFECT dropDefault, DROPEFFECT dropList, CPoint point);
```

[Documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/coledroptarget-class?view=vs-2019)

Comment: You seem to be asking several different questions. Perhaps you should post each as a separate StackOverflow question.

Comment: Well the idea was not to ask several question, but to ask one, list some possible ideas I had about the answer, and why the don't convince me... maybe I wasn't very good at writing. Sorry.

Comment: StackOverflow works on the basic principle of "one specific question, one specific answer". Every question should ask one thing and one thing only. And that thing should be something that can be given a single specific answer. Questions asking multiple questions or asking questions that can be interpreted into multiple answers are, generally, too broad and should usually be split into multiple individual questions.

Comment: Maybe [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) could be helpful

Comment: The [`IDropTarget::Drop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nf-oleidl-idroptarget-drop) interface passes a `grfKeyState` argument. I don't know, why the MFC implementation of `COleDropTarget` decided to drop this argument. I also don't know, whether MFC provides other drop target implementations. In case it doesn't, the solution would be to implement your own [`IDropTarget` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nn-oleidl-idroptarget).

Comment: @jab: `GetAsyncKeyState` is not a solution to the problem of determining the **synchronous** key state.

Comment: @IInspectable or rather `GetKeyState` then?

Comment: @jab: `GetKeyState` cannot travel back in time either. You only enter `IDropTarget::Drop` *after* having released whichever mouse button (or keyboard input) was used to initiate the drag and drop operation.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks for your remark. I believe that it led me to find an answer.

Comment: Imagine I think I found the answer, but I'm not sure, and I'd like to ask whether some expert can confirm... so, what should I do? Click "Answer yor question" and write there? (But it would be actually another question, not a sure positive answer) Or write all in a comment like this? (But it would be long and I'll cite some code... maybe it doesn't fit very well in a comment). Or maybe edit the initial question? (Wouldn't @JesperJuhl be upset if I put yet another question?) Start a "brand new" question (not linked with this page)?

Comment: Try it out. If it works then add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the thing appear to actually work (at least, with the MFC impementation found in Visual C++ version 10, alias 2010).

How the user IInspectable remarked, "*The `IDropTarget::Drop` interface passes a `grfKeyState` argument. [...] the MFC implementation of `COleDropTarget` decided to drop this argument.*"

Well, it's possible to debug the part where the implementation receives this parameters (and doesn't pass it to `OnDrop`): it's in the source `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\oledrop2.cpp` (or similar path).
The relevant part is in the function:

`STDMETHODIMP COleDropTarget::XDropTarget::Drop(THIS_ LPDATAOBJECT lpDataObject, DWORD dwKeyState, POINTL pt, LPDWORD pdwEffect)`

A quick debug shows that `dwKeyState` is actually passed, but (here) it has already lost the information about the mouse button.

Another fact: this `COleDropTarget::XDropTarget::Drop` calls still once `COleDropTarget::OnDragover` (that, this time, will receive the last update about the status of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys, but no info about the mouse button), and then `COleDropTarget::OnDropEx` or `COleDropTarget::OnDrop` (if the -`Ex` has not been overridden).

So it's unimportant to try to access `dwKeyState` from `COleDropTarget::OnDrop`: the only way to determine the mouse button at droptime is to remember it from a previous `COleDropTarget::OnDragover`.
The info about mouse button will come from the last-but-one call (if not even an earlier one?), so it has to be stored separately (storing just the last `dwKeyState` and using it at droptime would not work).

That's what I understood. If an expert can confirm, or wants to point out mistakes, (s)he's welcome.